# What's the recommended way to use GeoIP2 with a varying mirror list?

Tags: web-server, redirect, geoip

I want to setup a webserver, where every HTTP request is directly redirected to a nearby mirror. So far we used the unfortunately no longer supported Perl module `Apache2::Geo::IP` together with Apache's `mod_perl` and the legacy `Geo::IP` from MaxMind Inc.

The mirror list will change from time to time and uses the simple association between URL and the country of this server:

```
https://www1.crest.fr/archive/ fr
https://www2.uchile.cl/arcivo/ cl
https://www3.blurbs.cc/sammlung/ de
```

E. g. an user located in Chile will be redirected to `https://www2.uchile.cl/arcivo/` etc.
A country may have more than one server, which all should be accessed, e.g. randomly or round-robin.

I'm looking for a solution with the GeoIP2 country databases which can run behind a reverse proxy (the old solution did not). What's the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: The recommend way today is to use IPv6 multicast addresses and throw the old IPv4 software into trash. https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml , reserve a single global IPv6 multicast address for your servers, give all your servers the same global IPv6 multicast address, change all DNS to that particular global IPv6 multicast address and watch the magic happen.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great. but these are not "my servers". Some volunteers provided fast web space in many countries, but I do not have the possibility to change DNS records on other than the main server.

Comment: It's not necessary to change all DNS records, but recommend. What is necessary, would be to assign all those servers an IPv6 multicast address.